# Comments Pagination as an unordered list

Tags: comments, pagination

I am currently using `<?php paginate_comments_links(); ?>` to display comments pagination. How can I customise this so that it uses a UL and LI? (Such as is possible with custom post pagination).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [paginate_comments_links()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_comments_links) is pretty much just a already customized version for comments of [paginate_links()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links), see the documentation for a deeper insight, you can use the parameter `type` for this.

```
paginate_comments_links( array( 'type' => 'list' ) );
```